# prevent Notepad++ from resizing when a new document is opened

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, aero-snap

I run notepad++ snapped to the side of my screen (using the Windows 7 Snap feature), however whenever I open a new document in Notepad++ by double clicking on the document from the desktop (as opposed to opening through the File menu) it unsnaps it and resizes to what I assume is the 'default' size. I can't just open from the file menu all the time either because I open documents from my FTP program directly into N++, so this constant snapping / unsnapping is very annoying.

How can I prevent this from happening and keep Notepad++ from being 'unsnapped' when a new document is opened?

Comment: That's crazy eh?  It seems to still think it's stuck to the side though, because if you Win-Left/RightArrow key it will jump to the next snapped position relative to where it was snapped, not where it ends up after opening the file. Seems like a NP++ paint issue, but who knows. I tested v5.9.6 (2011-10-31) on Win 7 32-bit.

Comment: found a work-around that works for me, but still not a true solution...

Comment: I've experienced the same problem, and suggest you file a bug report with the N++ devs as it most certainly seems that this is the case (or at least a feature request).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This a work-around but it is a successful work-around: when the window gets 'unsnapped' on document open it resizes it to the size the window was before you snapped it. Ergo if you drag the window to the size of half your monitor, then snap it to the side (or just leave it, no need to snap it at this point) when it 'unsnaps' it basically stays in the same position.

Again, a work-around but one that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy workaround:

Just drag your files into the N++ window to open them (instead of double-clicking, right-click & open with, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

another work-around.

1. Open file_a.txt new np++ window
2. Open Exploler window
3. Drag & Drop file_b.txt to np++ window. (not double-click)

Answer (score 0):

This "answer" is really for reference. There are quite a few bugs already written against for the breaking of aerosnap against Notepad++, a search turned up six.

http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/search/?q=snap

Of these, one in particular seems to address the issue. This issue has a devised fix which is slated for [next release](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/patches/milestone/Next_release/) as of today, June 6th, 2013.

http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/patches/436/